# Jquery: How to target the parent ul and count the li's held?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jstree to build a tree menu. 
When you select an item in the tree a div on the right brings up certain information. The information can be deleted. 
When it is deleted I remove that item from the tree.
The problem is when the last li is removed from the ul, I need to remove the ul and also remove the "open" and "close" classes from the parent li and add the class "leaf". 
I am having a hard time targeting the ul and in turn targeting the parent li as well. 
I have to use the "clicked" class as a starting reference.

Here is the tree html:

```
<li id="447" class="open">
     <a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>ZigBee Remote Pairing-D</a>
     <ul>
         <li id="470" class="leaf last clicked">
               <a href="#"><ins>&nbsp;</ins>RCA TV2 - Audio Quality-F</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </li>
```

here is the jquery:

```
var numLi = $(".clicked").parent("ul:first > li").size();//get number of li in ul             
if (numLi == 1){
    $(".clicked").parent("ul:first").parent("li:first").removeClass().addClass("leaf");
}
$(".clicked").parent("li:first").remove();//remove the list item from the tree
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
var clickedLi = $('.clicked').parent('li');
var parentUlOfClickedLi = clickedLi.parent('ul');
if (parentUlOfClickedLi.children('li').length === 1) {
    parentUlOfClickedLi.parent('li')
        .removeClass('open close')
        .addClass('leaf');
}
clickedLi.remove();
```

Comment: I swear i tried this, maybe my syntax was wrong. Oh well, thank you very much this solved my issue. You Rock!